# Scheduling a controller to run every one hour in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, scheduler

I have a console application which does some operations when run and I generate an image of it using docker. Now, I would like to deploy it to Kubernetes and run it every hour, is it possible that I could do it in K8?

I have read about Cron jobs but that's being offered only from version 1.4

Comment: So, what's the problem? `Cronjob` is indeed what you need. It works fine as described in docs. You can set `@hourly` cron for your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer. Sure, you can do it with a [CronJob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/) and yes it does create a Pod. You can configure [Job History Limits](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/#jobs-history-limits) to control how many failed, completed pods you want to keep before Kubernetes deletes them.

Note that CronJob is a subset of the [Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/) resource.